# WitnessScript vs. Script Witness

Tags: segregated-witness, script, bip174-psbt

In [BIP 174/PSBT](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0174.mediawiki), there is a PSBT Input key-value pair called "PSBT_IN_WITNESS_SCRIPT" (0x05) and another called "PSBT_IN_FINAL_SCRIPTWITNESS" (0x08). What is the difference between a WitnessScript and a scriptWitness?

From what I understood, a witness script is the witness data for a single input (the signatures and scripts that unlock it). Is the scriptWitness something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSBT_IN_WITNESS_SCRIPT is specifically the actually executed script for a P2WSH or P2SH-P2WSH scriptPubKey being spent. It is added by an Updater who knows it.

PSBT_IN_FINAL_SCRIPTWITNESS is the witness stack needed to spend an output, including scripts, signatures, public keys, ... whatever is needed. It is created by a Finalizer, using other fields necessary (including PSBT_IN_WITNESS_SCRIPT) to produce it.

Comment: To clarify, SCRIPTWITNESS is the Segwit equivalent of ScriptSig, while WITNESS_SCRIPT is the Segwit equivalent of the redeemScript?

Or is WITNESS_SCRIPT the script for ScriptHash outputs, and it is separate by the redeemScript?

Comment: The scriptWitness (PSBT_IN_FINAL_SCRIPTWITNESS) is the per-input witness stack, so indeed more or less equivalent to scriptSig (for _all_ segwit spends, not just P2WSH). The witness script (PSBT_IN_WITNESS_SCRIPT) is the executed script in P2WSH - similar to the redeemScript is P2SH.